# how to count words after ellipsis

Tags: javascript, css

I'm currently using the css property ellipsis to add an ellipsis to the end of my line.  However, I also want to display the number of words after the ellipsis.  For instance

```
.names {
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    white-space: nowrap;
    width: X;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

<div class="names">Tim, Tom, Mary, Bob, Sam, John</div>
```

Shows

> Tim, Tom, Mary, ...

But, in this case I would want to show that the ellipsis represents 3 other names.

> Tim, Tom, Mary, ... and 3 others

What's the minimal way to do this, either in javascript or with css.  I'm using a webview in an iOS app and this will have to get calculated on every row item in a table so I would need to have a very lightweight js function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably need a lot more rigid requirements in order to give you a better / more robust code for this.  But I assume something like this is what you were looking for.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xf47e/3/

I don't know how you are currently dealing with your code issues but I'd be surprised if you haven't faced the issue of H... aka a half cut word already as well as many other problems that arise with the fact that character widths are most likely not constant with whatever font you are using.

```js
var names;
$(document).ready(function() {
  names = $('p.test').text().split(',');
  for (i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
    if (i < names.length - 1)
      $('p.test2').append(names[i] + ',');
    else
      $('p.test2').append(names[i]);
    console.log(i + " " + $('p.test2').width());
    if ($('p.test2').width() > 100) {
      break;
    }
  }
  $('p.test2').append(' ... and ' + (names.length - i + 1) + ' others.');
});
```

```css
p.test {
  width: 100px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

p.test2 {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div>
    <p class="test">Tom, Bob, Harry, Dick, John, James, Smith, Paul</p>
    <p class="test2"></p>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Cool, almost works.  One small bug would be to do names.length - (i+1) to get the right number of others.  I think this plus some testing to make sure to only run this only when an ellipsis is created could work

Comment: I always write names.length - i + 1. I have no idea why I did it wrong this time. :( Fixed.

Answer (score 2):

The only way I know to do this is to add the words one at a time, and measure the height of the element as you go.  When the height changes, you've reached your limit...

Comment: +1... I found the same thing to be the case. Posted a quick example of how I solved it recently.

Answer (score 0):

That's easy squeezy lemon peasy...

```
var orginalStr = "Tim, Tom, Mary, Bob, Sam, John";
var elStr = "Tim, Tom, Mary, ...".substring(0, "Tim, Tom, Mary, ...".indexOf("...")); 
//That should give you "Tim, Tom, Mary, ";
var count = originalStr.replace(elStr, "").split(",").length;
```

Comment: This is a simplification assuming your string is always going to be non-null and will always have ellipsis.

Comment: Sorry I meant the number of words in my original string that gets cut off by the ellipsis.  I've updated my question to reflect that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a bootstrapped piece of code that plays with CSS rules. It checks whether the `width()` is bigger than the parent `div` and displays `and X others` if it overflows.

```
<style>
    #container {width: 170px;white-space: nowrap; overflow: hidden;text-overflow: ellipsis;}
    #words {display: inline}
</style>
<div id="container"><div id="words">Mary</div></div><div id="others"></div>
<input type="button" onclick="addName();" value="add" />
<script>
var namesAfterEllipsis = 0;
function addName() {
  $("#words").append(", Tom");
  if ($("#words").width() >= $("#container").width())
    $("#others").html("and " + ++namesAfterEllipsis + " other" + (namesAfterEllipsis > 1 ? "s" : ""));
}
</script>
```

You can see it run [there](http://jsfiddle.net/TtyLd/)

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something like this and it works well in `WebView` on Android. From memory (using jQuery but can be adapted easily enough):

```
var names = $('.names');
names.data('original', names.text());
names.data('truncated', 0);

function truncate() {
    var n = names[0], t = names.text();
    if (n.scrollWidth > n.clientWidth) {
        names.data('truncated', names.data('truncated') + 1);
        names.text(t.substring(0, t.lastIndexOf(' ')));
        // remove one word, and let the DOM update
        setTimeout(truncate);
    } else {
        // set the text back to the original value
        // names.data('truncated') should now have the number of truncated words
        names.text(names.data('original'));
    }
}

truncate();
```